# change keybord language in ms-dos using assembly

Tags: assembly, keyboard, dos

i m bigner in assembly
i want to start a project using assembly language
this program must change my keybord from english to another language such as turkish in MS-DOS environment
in google i search and cant find any link for this
anybody can help me
regards

Edit Question :

for a project i need to change typing keyboard language . this project must written by assembly in MS-DOS 6.22 platform.
I'm beginner in assembly.
i don't know how can i define fonts in assembly
if you can please exlain with more details.

/Edit

Comment: This is pretty broad. What part do you need help with? What have you built so far?

Comment: Are you really programming in MS-DOS? You almost certainly do not want to learn assembly language on a dead operating system. You can learn assembly language on Windows or Linux, or a modern embedded platform.

Comment: I believe changing keyboard layout on MS-DOS involves loading the correct driver at boot time. Don't think you can change that later.

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/dos/keyb/xkeyb/

Comment: @BoPersson I've once written an unloadable keyboard/font Cyrillic driver. So, you should be able to change the characters at any time if you really want to. You're limited to 8 bits per char, though, so one language at a time.

Comment: @BoPersson: I don't know about "newer" MS-DOS versions, but on 3.x you could run `KEYB SP` or `KEYBSP` (depending on version) at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MS-DOS has any internationalization. If you want a Turkish keyboard, you either need a Turkish version of MS-DOS, or a real OS. Because string handling on DOS and going through the BIOS is so limited, multibyte characters would need programs designed for them. Also, because MS-DOS (and all DOSes) do most of their IO through the BIOS, and the BIOS most probably doesn't support Turkish characters (unless its a Turkish BIOS). This is why most modern operating systems by-step the BIOS completely and use their own text and keyboard drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad. But I can give a few hints on how to implement something like a keyboard layout switcher for DOS.

You will need to do 3 things:

1. Implement your own IRQ1 (int 9) ISR to receive keyboard input and manually store the scan codes and characters in the BIOS' data area and update the states of the alt, control and shift keys in the BIOS data area.
2. Hook int 10h with your own ISR to load and activate the 8x8 and 8x16 fonts (if the display is VGA or better, 8x8 and 8x14 if it's EGA) for your language when a text mode is set.
3. Make the program a DOS resident program (using e.g. DOS int 27h).

See Ralf Brown's Interrupt List for the description of int 10h, int 27h and the BIOS data area. Look up other places for interrupt handling and keyboard I/O via ports.

Comment: dear Alexey Frunze , hanks alot bcause of ur usefull answer . at begin i said that i'm new on assembly language . please describe with detail if possible . regards